# Module "@ngrx/effects" has no exported member "Effect"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

After angular upgrade “Effect” was not available in "@ngrx/effects". But we used “Effect” in our old code we are getting issues.

```
export class DictionaryService {

@Effect({dispatch: false})

  authActions$ = this.actions$.pipe(

    ofType<Login>(LOGIN),

    tap(() => {

      this.dictionaryKeys.forEach(key => {

        this.getData(key).pipe(take(1)).subscribe();

      });

    }));

}
```

Getting issue at `“@Effect({dispatch:false})”`. How to solve this issue?

Comment: The Effect decorator was deprecated (and eventually removed) quite a while ago. It was replaced with a functional equivalent called createEffect.